# Error while developing android application using ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am developing my first  app using android ndk, i tried to configure the location of ndk-build in properties>c/c++>build but still i get the same error every time, i tried to remove .cmd from ndk-build(changed from ndk-build.cmd to ndk-build and vice versa), but iam still getting the same error, here is my screen shot[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `D:/Work/eclipse/android-ndk/ndk-build.cmd` without **$**, if you really unzipped the **ndk** zip file into `d:\work\eclipse\android-ndk` on your PC. It would be even better to keep the "build command" default (android-ndk.cmd), and define the path to NDK as shown in the screen capture below:

[image: Android/NDK/NDK Location]
<sub>(source: [suvitruf.ru](http://suvitruf.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Android-NDK-path.png))</sub>